# i18n in Google App Engine - PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, internationalization

I'm trying to implement i18n in GAE - PHP via the gettext extension, but it fails, I suppose the extension is not enabled in GAE as of now.

I've tried using the php-gettext class, and it works fine, but I'm a bit concerned about its speed. As you can see [in this benchmark](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2006/04/10/benchmarking-php-localization-is-gettext-fast-enough/) the class is the slowest method.

Do you know any other way I can use? I'd prefer to use the php-gettext class and the .po files rather than string ids, but I also don't want to slow down the site.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since app engine 1.9.22, the intl extension is available, although it has to be activated. Just include it in your php.ini file as such:

```
extension = "intl.so"
```

(as mentioned in [Google App Engine's issue tracker on June 11th 2015](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10080))

Answer (score 0):

You can try the library [php-gettext-memcached](https://github.com/tengyifei/php-gettext-memcached). It was built on top of the php-gettext library, and caches parsed translation data using Google's memcached service, hence increasing its speed.

[Performance benchmark](http://www.thinkingandcomputing.com/2014/02/16/speeding-up-gettext-on-app-engine/)

*Disclaimer: I wrote this library.*